# Negating this regex - how?

Tags: regex, replace

I have this regex: `[A-Z][A-Z] \d\d`

I want to use it to replace everything that does NOT match with blanks (or any other character). How can I do that? I negated character class does not work in this case, because the regex itself has 2 char classes.

A short part of the string looks like that:

```
<div class=""></div>CL 17 </a><br>
```

Only the CL 17 should remain, the rest should be blank.

**Note:** I noticed that this seems to be complicated, so I solved it by writing a small PHP script, which gets a list of the matches (preg_match_all) and handles those in a way thats ok for my case.

Comment: So you want change `foo AB 12 barXY 89baz` into `****AB 12****XY 89***`?

Comment: That's not going to be easy with regexes. I'm off to lunch now but will try to think of something later.

Comment: @user1638055 - Depending on how you are actually going to use it, perhaps a valid alternative could be to dump the **matching** strings to a file *(essentially equivalent with replacing everything that doesn't match with an empty character)*

Comment: @Lieven: The problem with that approach is that it won't preserve the number of non-matching characters. He wants to replace each single one with a replacement letter.

Comment: Thanks guys, please dont bother any longer, I solved it by writing a small PHP script, which gets a list of the matches (preg_match_all), thats enough for my scenario.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - well, it appears OP doesn't need to preserve them at all but now we'll never know what you would have come up with :)

Comment: @Lieven: Good to hear that. I'm pretty sure we would have had to spell out all the possible combinations...

Comment: @user1638055: You might want to post your solution and accept it as your own answer. This could help others who come across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After your last edit I would suggest:

```
.*?([A-Z]{2} \d{2}).*?(?=[A-Z]{2} \d{2}|$)
```

then replace with the first group.

(answer before edit):

```
[^A-Z][^A-Z]\S\D{2}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, jEdit supports all kinds of complex regexes, I tried the negative lookahead below, but it did not work, too.

Answer (score 0):

following last post edit you're looking for a backward reference in the replace string:

```
pattern:  ^.*?([A-Z][A-Z] \d\d).*$
replace:  $1
```

maybe equivalent to this

```
pattern:  ^.*?(?=[A-Z][A-Z] \d\d)|(?<=[A-Z][A-Z] \d\d).*$
replace:  **nothing**
```